# iOS: Navigation to a specific tab after editing tabs' positions

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, ibaction

I have an application with a `UITabBarController` which contains 6 tabs. I also have an `IBAction` which has the following code

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
```

to navigate to another tab (`Profile Tab`). It woks perfectly except when I go to the `More` tab and I change the position of my tabs. Then, the `IBAction` doesn't send me to `Profile Tab` but to the second tab, which can be any other tab.

How can I navigate using my `IBAction` to go to the specific tab and not by using the tabs order?

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain a mapping of the purpose of the view controllers managed by the tab controller and what they are for. If each tab has a view controller of a different class then you could use that and search for it (but that isn't ideal...).

The better option is to maintain a dictionary where the keys are the tab / view identifiers (which should be defined constants) and the values are the view controllers associated with those identifiers (and managed by the tab controller).

Now, when you want to switch tab you don't use `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;`, you use

```
UIViewController *controller = self.config[XXXX];
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = controller;
```

*(where `XXXX` is the constant identifier and `config` is the mapping dictionary)*

Answer (score 0):

UITabbarController has selectedViewController which can come to rescue in this particular situation. If I am not mistaken, you have UINavigationController, which contains other view controllers, as child of UITabbarController. If it is so, you can assign selectedViewController property of UITabbarController to particular UINavigationController provided that you have either ivars or properties in place to refer to those UINavigationControllers. And by doing so, you are not bound to any tab index.

```
UINavigationController *moreNavigationController = [UINavigationController alloc] …];
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = moreNavigationController;
```